# $c \le n < m < c+1 \implies m-n<1 $

Tags: inequality

This should be simple, but I got stuck trying to manipulate the inequalities.

Show that:
$c \le n < m < c+1 \implies m-n<1 $, all are real numbers.

I have that $m< c + 1 \implies m-n<c+1-n $ and $c<m \implies c-n<m-n $. How do I get $m-n<1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m<c+1$ and $-n\le -c$, so $m-n<c+1-c=1$.

Answer (score 2):

m - n < c + 1 - c = 1 .......

Answer (score 1):

Since $c\le n$ then $-c \ge -n$ and since $c+1>m$ then
$$1=c+1-c>m-n$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $m<c+1$ and $c\leq n$

now, since $c\leq n$, then $c+1\leq n+1$

As a result: \begin{eqnarray}
m<c+1&\leq& n+1\\
\therefore m&<&n+1\\
m-n&<&1
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

$$m<c+1 \Rightarrow \textbf{c+1-m>0}$$
$$c \leq n \Rightarrow \textbf{n-c} \geq\textbf{0}$$
So 
$$c+1-m+n-c>0$$ or $$1>m-n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Through your given inequality what you need to picture is that $m, n \in [c, c + 1)$. Hence the difference between the two elements is definitely less than $1$. For an alternative method:

Suppose $m - n \ge 1 \implies m \ge n + 1$. Then since $n \in [c, c + 1) \implies n \ge c \implies m = n + 1 \ge c + 1 \implies m \not \in [c, c + 1) $ leading to a contradiction.